# How do you figure out the best way for system architecture of your application's front-end?

Tags: reactjs, architecture, frontend, system, web-frontend

So the question is open-ended as it is the title. I am 1.5 years old front-end developer (learning and professional work included)who's just familiarizing myself with stuff like abstractions, structuring codebase for apps to not have redundant copies of components with the same functionality and I do see straightforward ways to do so but I can't help but wonder if there's a particular method to go about this and make decisions. Any suggestions, advice, system to learn from would be really helpful.

Comment: That's too general at the moment.

Comment: okay, for example, I learnt a couple of months ago that my codebase could be split into pages, components and the appropriate amount of information could be abstracted based on the use case of the component. My question is how do you decide what's the appropriate amount of information that can be/should be abstracted?

Comment: [Rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(computer_programming)). Also, there are general [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Comment: Copy that! thanks for the rule of three :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.